# offsetTop adds up margin of its child element <p>

Tags: html, css

Here's the code:

```js
var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
var demoDiv = document.getElementById("demo");
demoDiv.innerHTML = "offsetLeft: " + testDiv.offsetLeft + "<br>offsetTop: " + testDiv.offsetTop;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border: 0px 0px 0px 0px
}

#test {
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p id="demo">offsetLeft: <br>offsetTop: </p>
</div>
```

**Output of code:**
offsetLeft: 0
offsetTop: 16

For some reason it adds up the spaces of `<p>` tag(i.e. 1em+1em=8px+8px=16px) which is a child of #test in the OffsetTop of #test.

[Look at the portion of page when #test is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oci9P.png)

[Look at when the p tag with id demo is highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqSc9.png)

**Expected output:**
offsetLeft: 0
offsetTop: 0

Answer (score 1):

This is because

> By default, browsers separate paragraphs with a single blank line [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)

So `p` got initial margin. If you'll set it to `0` it would give you the expected result:

```js
var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
var demoDiv = document.getElementById("demo");
demoDiv.innerHTML = "offsetLeft: " + testDiv.offsetLeft + "<br>offsetTop: " + testDiv.offsetTop;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border: 0px 0px 0px 0px
}

#test {
  position: relative
}

p {margin: 0}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p id="demo">offsetLeft: <br>offsetTop: </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I wanted to know the reason as to why it is adding margin(top and bottom) of 2em/16px of a child element(#demo) into it's offsetTop.

Comment: sorry its 1em**

Comment: @AnchalGupta as quoted the initial style of `p` element on browsers is with this blank line (1em) separate it from top and bottom. Try change `line-height` attribute and you will get different results. If you want fully control the space add `margin: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

The `<p>` tag default margin is extrapolating the div area and pushing it down.

If you add some padding `<div>` or if you set the `<p>` margin to 0 you will get the expected values.

```js
var testDiv = document.getElementById("test");
var demoDiv = document.getElementById("demo");
demoDiv.innerHTML = "offsetLeft: " + testDiv.offsetLeft + "<br>offsetTop: " + testDiv.offsetTop;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#test {
  padding: 2em;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p id="demo">offsetLeft: <br>offsetTop: </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I didn't quite understand the first sentence
The <p> tag default margin is extrapolating the div area and pushing it down.

Also my aim is not to get the expected output but the reason behind it. Why is the #test's sffsetTop adds margin of 1em/16px of its child element(#demo)? Because offsetTop is something relative position of the current element with its nearest ancestor which is not static (in this case its <body>)

Comment: Each browser has a set of default CSS rules. If you create an HTML with just a `<p>` tag and no style, it will still have the margin, and this margin can have different sizes in other browsers. 
Your `<div>` tag did not had any height or dimension, so it was following the [auto height blocking rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#root-height).